# Form_for namespaced route for a resource with multiple states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Blog` model which has different states.  In order to keep a skinny controller and follow the convention of only having CRUD operations per controller, I followed [DHH's namespacing controllers pattern](http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/) and namespaced out the `Blog` controller.

Now I have a `Blogs::NewDraft` controller, a `Blogs::AwaitingApproval` controller, and a `Blogs::Active` controller.

I have the following in my `_form.html.erb` for creating a new draft for a blog.  It works for creating a new record, but it does not work for updating an existing record:

```
# app/views/blogs/new_drafts/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @blog, url: :blogs_new_drafts  do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

When I go to update the draft it throws this error:

> No route matches [PATCH] "blogs/new_drafts"

I'm having trouble figuring out why it is saying there is a routing error when I update here because when I run `rake routes` it does have a route for a PATCH to `blogs/new_drafts#update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your URL:

```
<%= form_for @blog, url: :blogs_new_draft(@blog)  do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The URL for your create action will differ from the update.  The update action URL needs to know *which* blog you are trying to update.

That said, if you are trying to share `_form` with the `new` and `edit` views, having a single `form` won't work, since you are providing custom URLs which will differ between those two actions.  There's ways to make it work (pass in the URL to the partial / instantiate the URL in your controller as a variable / add the form tag directly to your new/edit views / etc), but something will need to be done.